# 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: android

i am trying to run this command
`keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Lenovo\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

in android studio termina but getting these error:

[image]

> My android studio is installed in G drive also my project files are in G drive

i tried this
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2\bin\keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Lenovo\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

but got `C:\Program` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double-quotes around the program name, as the directory contains spaces:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2\bin\keytool.exe" -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Lenovo.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: As a separate comment, you really, really, really should not be using JDK 10.  Use at least 17 if you can't go any newer.

Comment: And another note, as you are doing development, why are you looking in JRE and not full JDK?

Comment: getting "Unexpected token '-list' in expression or statement"

Comment: I suspect you have a VERY old JRE which has different set of parameters.  Try running keytool without any further parameters and see what it suggests.